# Single page hit counter php sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/html radio portal website template that uses an sql database.

The channels are generated dynamically from the database. The one thing the author of the script forgot to add was a hit counter for each channel. 
So i added a row to my channel table in my database named counter.

The structure of my data base field im trying to edit is

Database "live"
Table"channel"
Row"counter"

I have used the following to ad a hit counter to the channel page.

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "*password") or 
    die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("live") or die(mysql_error()); 
    //Adds one to the counter

    mysql_query("UPDATE counter where id=$chnid SET counter = counter + 1");
```

Because pages are generated using the channel id from the a row in my channel table, im finding it difficult to get the counter to populate.

I have used the above mentioned script before I edited it in a separate file to test does it work and it works fine and I think it worked fine because the structure of the demo database was much simpler.

Here is the demo script that works before I butchered it.

```
   <?php
     // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password") or 
     die(mysql_error()); 
      mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
      //Adds one to the counter

     mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1");

     //Retrieves the current count

    $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM counter"));

    //Displays the count on your site

    print "$count[0]";

    ?>
```

So I guess the question is how can I get the demo script to work with my database structure.

Thanks
[image: Here is a pic of my database structure]

Comment: removed incompatibe (MS)SQL-Server tag

Comment: You really need to stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Move over to `mysqli_*` or preferably PDO prepared statements

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is incorrect. You first set your `SETs`. then youre `WHEREs`. It should be:

```
UPDATE counter SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE channel_id = $chnid
```

Dont use `mysql()` as mentioned.